# Is there any size limit on Apigee proxy?

Tags: proxy, size, chunked, apigee

I have configured a simple passthrough proxy for my backend API. It's working fine for URL's that return short data. I have one URL that returns around 700KB of data. For this, it returns only partial data (around 54K) with 200 status. Is there a way to increase the size limit on the API proxy?

It doesn't even return the 'chunked' response :-(

Comment: Are you building it in standard proxy xml or in Node/javascript/python?

Comment: @r3mus - I am building it in a standard proxy, nothing special about it. As mike-malloy below mentions it, looks like there was some issue in router component. It seems to be resolved now and my api proxy works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue should now be resolved.  If you run into any problems in the future, please contact us.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to a recent change to the router component.  We are currently evaluating the best way to alleviate this issue.  The engineering team is engaged in solving this.